# How can I define an XSL variable and assign a value in xsl:choose

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to define a variable named 'category' in XSL, assign a value to it, and reuse that variable a bit down in my code.
if objecttype=1 the variable value should be 'car'
if objecttype=2 the variable value should be 'bus'

How can I achieve that?

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<head><style type="text/css">body{font-size:11px;font-family:Verdana;}</style></head>
<body>
Dear
<xsl:for-each select="user">
<xsl:value-of select="firstname"/><xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
<xsl:if test="middlename != ''"> 
<xsl:value-of select="middlename"/><xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
<xsl:value-of select="user/lastname"/>,<br/>
<br/>
You have created a company listing for "<xsl:value-of select="user/objecttitle"/>".<br/>
<br/>
Did you know Google uses the number of Facebook 'likes' for webpages in its rankings?<br/>
You can like you page here: 
<xsl:for-each select="user"> 
<xsl:variable name="category"> 
    <xsl:choose> 
        <xsl:when test="objecttype='1'">car</xsl:when> 
        <xsl:when test="objecttype='2'">bus</xsl:when> 
    </xsl:choose> 
</xsl:variable> 
</xsl:for-each> 
<a href="http://www.mydomain.com/{$category}/{user/objectid}/{user/objecturl}">Click here to go to your company listing now.</a><br/>
Kind regards,<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a common error for XSL newcomers.  The correct approach is:

```
<xsl:variable name="category">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="objecttype='1'">car</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="objecttype='2'">bus</xsl:when>
    ... etc
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

In your example, the variable is local to the `<xsl:when...>` tag.

Comment: Ok, so I tried the following two things, but how do I retrieve the value of the variable? {$category} doesnt seem to work...
1.
<xsl:for-each select="user">
<xsl:variable name="category">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="objecttype='1'">car</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="objecttype='2'">bus</xsl:when>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
</xsl:for-each>

2.
<xsl:variable name="category">
<xsl:for-each select="user">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="objecttype='1'">car</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="objecttype='2'">bus</xsl:when>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>

Comment: You'll have to expand your post to include an example of how you're using this.  Edit your post and add a complete simplified example stylesheet using the variable.

Comment: Ok, I added the full xsl code, hope that clarifies my need! :)

Comment: In XSL, variables are scoped just like in block-structured languages.  You defined the variable inside the `for-each`, so it does not exist outside the `for-each` block.  I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish... should the link be inside the `for-each`?  If not, is it your intention to have a single link with the category for the _last_ user?  That's what the code would seem to indicate as-is.

Comment: I now have this, which works:
    <xsl:for-each select="user"> 
    <xsl:variable name="category"> 
    <xsl:choose> 
        <xsl:when test="objecttype='1'">car</xsl:when> 
        <xsl:when test="objecttype='2'">bus</xsl:when> 
    </xsl:choose> 
    </xsl:variable> 
    <a href="http://www.mydomain.com/{$category}/{objectid}/{objecturl}">go to your company listing</a><br/>
    </xsl:for-each> 
 
So the question has been answered,but Im still wondering how I could define a variable OUTSIDE a block, and then within any block assign a value to that variable which I can then use anywhere.

Comment: You can't. XSL is a functional language, and variables are read-only after they are defined.